# $I_n=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin^n x\cos xdx(n=0,1,2...)$, find $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}I_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$I_n=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin^n x\cos xdx(n=0,1,2...), find \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}I_n$$
My try:
$$\int_o^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin^nx\cos xdx=\frac{1}{n+1}\sin^{\frac{1+n}{n}}x\big|_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}=\frac{1}{n+1}(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^{\frac{1}{n}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
We get:
$$I_n=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^{\frac{1}{n}}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
What's the next step?

Comment: Please don’t vandalise your posts. There was no point in deleting the section containing your efforts, that actually only harms the post and makes it likely to be closed or deleted (which happened 4 hours after your edit)

Comment: Got it! I feel guilty for the obvious problem.@FShrike

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative method using geometric series
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^{\pi/4}\sin^nx\cos xdx=\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos x}{1- \sin x}dx=-\ln(1-\sin x)\Big\rvert_0^{\pi/4}=\ln(2+\sqrt2)$$

Answer (score 5):

You should have: $$\int_0^{\pi/4}\sin^n(x)\cos(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{n+1}\sin^{\color{red}{n+1}}(x)\Big |_0^{\pi/4}=\frac{1}{n+1}2^{-\frac{n+1}{2}}$$So that the series is: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}2^{-n/2}=-\ln(1-x)|_{2^{-1/2}}=-\ln(1-1/\sqrt{2})=\ln(2+\sqrt{2})$$

Comment: @AnneBauval For some reason the OP vandalised their own post. At the time of answering they had included effort